# Is there a way to share relationship between composable objects?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I was wondering... is there a way to have relationship between composable objects?

If I have a Box() and I want to be sure that it's zIndex is the highest, hence, I need to query all of the Box()s beneath it for their zIndex. Is there a way to query another composable object modifier value?

Also, lets say I drag this box around, and I want to 'sense' if it hits another box, so, I have to expose the other box offset values so to that draggable Box() so that it will 'know' that it collided.

Comment: Compose is fundamentally different that the view system, sir, as in the `Composables` are not really `object`s. They are just functions which 'emit' UI. What you wish for can certainly be achieved, but there are APIs for that, which you'll have to go through to understand the basics. Consider taking [The Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose) as a good starter.

Comment: You need to pass it the highest zIndex if you want it to have the highest zIndex.